# badly broken Ubuntu 18.04 install

Tags: 18.04, upgrade

I had Ubuntu 16.04 or whatever running on my system (off a RAID disk pair). I tried to upgrade to 18.04 over it. Eventually I had the upgrade say that it is broken, can't finish, possibly left in an unstable state. I tried to 'repair' the problem, but -- stupidly -- uninstalled ubuntu-desktop (or whatever) & then rebooted.

Now 18.04 tries to boot, says that it is starting Light Desktop (or whatever) & the text cursor is blinking in the upper left corner on an empty screen & nothing happens. Obviously the desktop sw is broken, but I don't know what to do. I have no install CD for 18.04 (& my setup is RAID, so I would need the server install CD, I think), & when I boot into recovery mode then the package manager can't find some ubuntu server to fix the broken display package (I guess).

I would greatly appreciate some handholding. Right now I'm running 14.04 off another drive & I don't even see the other system because it is on those RAID pair of disks & this install has no support for those disks (this install happened in another machine).

Please, please help!

Comment: Please make a LiveUSB https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#0 
 after verifying the downloaded ISO https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 so you will have the necessary tools to work with.

Comment: Thank you K7AAY for your pointers, I'm about to follow them & will report back with my results.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to boot off a Live CD and fix the situation. If the proper raid drivers are not on the Live CD that is okay, you can install them after booting. It will install temporarily to memory, and stay until you reboot.

What I would personally do, is back everything up that I cared to save and start a clean install. Then you can restore your data from backup. You might loose some settings that way, but if you back up your whole user folder you can restore settings files as needed later.

Comment: Thank you, izzy, for your advice. I'll report back with my success (or lack thereof).